# Merge Partition Locking table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

I have a BIG table with 400kk rows.

I want to partition this table but I`m having a problem when merging the two older Partition Functions.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PartitionDemo](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [myDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [variable] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_PartitionDemo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [myDate] ASC,
    [Id] ASC
)ON [PartitionDemo_PS](mydate)
)

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PartitionDemo_PS] AS PARTITION [PartitionDemo_PF] TO ([PartitionDemo_FG_Prev], [PartitionDemo_FG_Historical], [PartitionDemo_FG_201609], [PartitionDemo_FG_201610], [PartitionDemo_FG_201611], [PartitionDemo_FG_201612], [PartitionDemo_FG_201701], [PartitionDemo_FG_201702], [PartitionDemo_FG_201703], [PartitionDemo_FG_201704])
GO

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PartitionDemo_PF](date) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (N'2015-03-01T00:00:00.000', N'2016-09-01T00:00:00.000', N'2016-10-01T00:00:00.000', N'2016-11-01T00:00:00.000', N'2016-12-01T00:00:00.000', N'2017-01-01T00:00:00.000', N'2017-02-01T00:00:00.000', N'2017-03-01T00:00:00.000', N'2017-04-01T00:00:00.000')
GO
```

This is my table with 400kk rows.

What I do to merge partition is:

```
CREATE TABLE [staging].[PartitionDemo](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [myDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [variable] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_PartitionDemo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [myDate] ASC,
    [Id] ASC
)ON [PartitionDemo_PS](mydate)
)
GO


ALTER TABLE PartitionDemo
SWITCH PARTITION 2 TO [staging].[PartitionDemo] PARTITION 2


ALTER TABLE PartitionDemo
SWITCH PARTITION 3 TO [staging].[PartitionDemo] PARTITION 3


ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [PartitionDemo_PF]()
    MERGE RANGE ('2016-03-01');
```

The problem is that it locks both tables while merging.

What is the workaround with this problem?

Comment: Is your intent to switch the data back into the source table after the merge?

Comment: Yes, i will switch back the data, I just don't write the script here because the problema is before it.

Comment: I have additional questions too long for comments.  Please join the chat in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139493/merge-partition-locking-table-in-sql-server

Comment: I have answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the first boundary with this function and scheme, all data before 2015-03-01 will be moved to the `PartitionDemo_FG_Prev` filegroup instead of the `PartitionDemo_FG_Historical` filegroup as intended.  I recommend a `NULL` partition boundary to ensure the first partition is always empty.  This will also allow you to remove files from this unused filegroup and facilitate partition maintenance going forward. See http://www.dbdelta.com/table-partitioning-best-practices/ for more information on this practice.

A brief schema modification lock will be acquired during the `SWITCH`, `MERGE`, and `SPLIT` operations but those should fast meta-data operations because no data movement is needed. The physical data movement is done by the staging table `CREATE INDEX...DROP_EXISTING-ON`, which also avoids a sort to rebuild the index. This script acquires an exclusive table lock during the `SWITCH`, `MERGE`, and `SPLIT` operations to avoid deadlocking with other activity.

```
--create staging table exactly like original table
CREATE TABLE [staging].[PartitionDemo](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [myDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [variable] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_PartitionDemo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [myDate] ASC,
        [Id] ASC
    ) ON [PartitionDemo_PS](mydate)
);

--create temporary partition function and scheme with desired end state
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [StagingPartitionDemo_PF](date) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (
      CAST(NULL AS datetime)     --NULL boundary ensures first parttion is always empty
    , N'2016-09-01T00:00:00.000' --upper boundary of historical data fg (less than this date)
    , N'2016-10-01T00:00:00.000'
    , N'2016-11-01T00:00:00.000'
    , N'2016-12-01T00:00:00.000'
    , N'2017-01-01T00:00:00.000'
    , N'2017-02-01T00:00:00.000'
    , N'2017-03-01T00:00:00.000'
    , N'2017-04-01T00:00:00.000'
    );
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [StagingPartitionDemo_PS] AS PARTITION [StagingPartitionDemo_PF] TO (
      [PartitionDemo_FG_Prev]
    , [PartitionDemo_FG_Historical]
    , [PartitionDemo_FG_201609]
    , [PartitionDemo_FG_201610]
    , [PartitionDemo_FG_201611]
    , [PartitionDemo_FG_201612]
    , [PartitionDemo_FG_201701]
    , [PartitionDemo_FG_201702]
    , [PartitionDemo_FG_201703]
    , [PartitionDemo_FG_201704]
    );
GO

SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRAN;

--acquire exclusive table lock to prevent deadlocking with concurrent activity
SELECT TOP(0) myDate FROM dboPartitionDemo WITH(TABLOCKX);

--switch first partition into staging (in case data exists before 2015-03-01)
ALTER TABLE dbo.PartitionDemo
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.PartitionDemo_PF(CAST(NULL AS datetime))
    TO [staging].[PartitionDemo] PARTITION $PARTITION.PartitionDemo_PF(CAST(NULL AS datetime));

--switch second partition into staging (on or after 2015-03-01 and before 2016-09-01)
ALTER TABLE dbo.PartitionDemo
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.PartitionDemo_PF('2015-03-01T00:00:00.000')
    TO [staging].[PartitionDemo] PARTITION $PARTITION.PartitionDemo_PF('2015-03-01T00:00:00.000');

--switch third partition into staging (on or after 2016-09-01 and before 2016-10-01)
ALTER TABLE dbo.PartitionDemo
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.PartitionDemo_PF('2016-09-01T00:00:00.000')
    TO [staging].[PartitionDemo] PARTITION $PARTITION.PartitionDemo_PF('2016-09-01T00:00:00.000');

COMMIT;
GO

--rebuild staging table on temporary partition scheme
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX pk_PartitionDemo ON staging.PartitionDemo(
        [myDate] ASC,
        [Id] ASC
    )
WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON)
ON [StagingPartitionDemo_PS](mydate);
GO

SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRAN;

--acquire exclusive table lock to prevent deadlocking with concurrent activity
SELECT TOP(0) myDate FROM dboPartitionDemo WITH(TABLOCKX);

--modify original partition scheme to match temporary one
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PartitionDemo_PS
    NEXT USED PartitionDemo_FG_Historical;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PartitionDemo_PF()
    SPLIT RANGE(CAST(NULL AS datetime));
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PartitionDemo_PF()
    MERGE RANGE('2015-03-01T00:00:00.000');

--switch historical data partition partition back to main table
ALTER TABLE staging.PartitionDemo
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.PartitionDemo_PF(NULL)
    TO dbo.[PartitionDemo] PARTITION $PARTITION.PartitionDemo_PF(CAST(NULL AS datetime));

--switch 2016-09-01 partition back to main table
ALTER TABLE staging.PartitionDemo
    SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.PartitionDemo_PF('2016-09-01T00:00:00.000')
    TO dbo.[PartitionDemo] PARTITION $PARTITION.PartitionDemo_PF('2016-09-01T00:00:00.000');

COMMIT;
GO
```

Comment: My first and last boundary will be always NULL =), I will try it today, thanks a LOT.